# WinForms - PerfromClick() doesn't work when the button is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, eventhandler

I created a form menu that is created dynamically and shows/hides the child items after clicking on the parent items. I have a code that checks the keyboard keys on the `BaseMenuForm`. When a shortcut is detected, then I need to perform the click event for the relevant button. My problem is that the `PerformClick()` event is not working when the children items are not visible.

I found a workaround by assigning the event to the `ShortcutAction` property.
I don't think that it is necessary to assign the same event twice but currently I don't know how to overcome this issue. I don't want to show all the menu items for the shortcuts.

You can see the "TODO" remarks and the second constructor that performs a workaround if the shortcut is configured. When the button is clicked by the user, the `Click` event work as expected, so it doesn't work programatically.

This is part of my code (only the relevant parts):

The following property is set on the designer. The `BaseMenuForm_KeyDown` event is called as expected.

```
BaseMenuForm.KeyPreview = true;
```

My Item class:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The menu item settings.
    /// </summary>
    public class MyItem : Button
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The keyboard keys shortcut.
        /// </summary>
        public Shortcut Shortcut { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The action that will be called by the shortcut.
        /// TODO: why not working when I call PerformClick()
        /// </summary>
        public Action ShortcutAction { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the item instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
        /// <param name="onClickEvent">The event that will be triggered on cick.</param>
        public MyItem(string name, string text, EventHandler onClickEvent) : this(name, text)
        {
            if (onClickEvent == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(onClickEvent));
            }
            else
            {
                Click += onClickEvent;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the item instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
        /// <param name="onClickEvent">The event that will be triggered on cick.</param>
        /// <param name="shortcut">The keyboard shortcut.</param>
        public MyItem(string name, string text, EventHandler onClickEvent, Shortcut shortcut) : this(name, text, onClickEvent)
        {
            ShortcutAction = () => onClickEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); //TODO: Why do I need this?
            Shortcut = shortcut;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

       
    }
```

BaseMenuForm: This class contains the form, every form that will inherit this form will have a menu.

```
        #region Shortcut

        private void BaseMenuForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckShortcut(e.KeyData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the pressed keys is a shortcut combination.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keyData">The keys.</param>
        private void CheckShortcut(Keys keyData)
        {
            var shortut = (Shortcut)keyData;
            Logger.LogDebug($"Got shortcut {shortut}");
            if(Shortcuts.TryGetValue(shortut, out var button) && button.ShortcutAction != null)
            {
                button.ShortcutAction();
                //button.PerformClick(); //TODO: why not working !
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogDebug("No click");
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the following questions:

1. Why [`PerfromClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) doesn't work for an invisible button?
2. What's a workaround for this issue?

**Answer to 1** - If you look at the [source code of the PerfromClick](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,845bec419ca23629) method, you see the first statement is a check: `if (CanSelect)` and if [follow the code further](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,45863e3b118ef2cd,references), you see the `CanSelect` method returns false when the control is not enabled or is not visible. So that's the reason.

**Answer to 2** - As a workaround, you can use the button's accessible object and [invoke the default action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject.dodefaultaction?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) which basically performs a click for a button:

```
button1.AccessibilityObject.DoDefaultAction();
```

Or as another workaround, use reflection to invoke the OnClick method:

```
button1.GetType().GetMethod("OnClick", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Invoke(button, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
```

Comment: I prefer to keep the following notes apart from the answer: It's almost always a better idea to handle shortcut keys by overriding ProcessCmdKey method. Menu component is also very nice and easy to use solution to assign and detect shortcuts. It also works when the menu is not visible. Also, if your button is invisible, it basically means you do not need it, you just need to create methods which you call when you detect the shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the key, one of your buttons is in focus. It prevents the parent control (BaseMenuForm) from handling this event.

Fix:

```
BaseMenuForm.KeyPreview = true;
```

I tried this code, it works as expected:

```
public class MyItem : Button
{
    public Shortcut Shortcut { get; }

    public MyItem(EventHandler onClickEvent, Shortcut shortcut)
    {
        Click += onClickEvent ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(onClickEvent));
        Shortcut = shortcut;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Shortcut, MyItem> _shortcuts;

    public Form1()
    {
        var myItems = new[]
        {
            new MyItem(OnClickEvent, Shortcut.CtrlG) {Left = 0, Text = "Ctrl+G"},
            new MyItem(OnClickEvent, Shortcut.CtrlH) {Left = 50, Text = "Ctrl+H"}
        };

        _shortcuts = myItems.ToDictionary(x => x.Shortcut);

        Controls.AddRange(myItems);

        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void OnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{((Button)sender).Text} Clicked!");
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_shortcuts.TryGetValue((Shortcut) e.KeyData, out var myItem))
        {
            myItem.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: MenuS]

Comment: Iconfigured the KeyPreview = true on the designer before posting the question. The KeyDown event is called and the method executes the action (my workaround). It does not work with PerformClick(). It is not related to the KeyDown property because the code is called as mentioned.

Comment: I think additional information is required because my sample code works with no issues.

Comment: I have the some code, my form inherits other forms but it should not affect the behavior. As mentioned only the PerformClick not working. I can get the shortcut from keyboard

Comment: Can you put my code on your form? Does it work?

Comment: I can see that my code works too when I create a new MyItem and add it to the shortcut dictionary in the form itself. The menu form derives three forms. It is not an issue because it works as mentioned. I added the code that initiate all the buttons from a manager class. I verified that the init method is called after the c'tors of the menu form. Please take a loook at the deviceSettingsItem , I added a remark because this is the only shortcut that works with the PerformClick(). I don't understand what is the difference.

Comment: I understood the issue!. All the buttons from the manager class are hidden (visible false) because they are sub menus in the panel of the parent item. When I show this buttons (click on the parent panel) and then use the shortcut, It works as expected. The deviceSettingsItem works because it is visible true but not assigned to the form. So I guess that I need to remove the items instead of changing the button visibility? I have many panels with docking to the top so when I click a parent, all the children are displayed in another panel. See the attached picture

Comment: I think you can extract the Shortcut and the handler to a separate class and use it in both places: inside MyItem to handle a regular Button click and in your dictionary. So, after that it won't depend on a button visibility.

Comment: Okay thank you. It is actually what I already did, just moving the code to anothe class... Thank you

Comment: Also I would suggest to see on a some kind of a Command pattern.