# How to make a form click a button when loaded?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms - Mainmenu form , that clicks to a registration from.

On the registration form, I have a button. I want the form to automatically click when the form is loaded. Below is what I have tried so far but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
public Membershipform()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Button_1.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: Have you considered taking the code in the button’s click event and putting it in a method? Then you could call it from the button click AND the forms constructor or load event.

Comment: @pm100 The registration form loads as normal , no errors. The button does not perform a click though

Comment: `when the form is loaded` ... which form?

Comment: and so what does happen, put in some breakpoints.

Comment: @jsotola the Membership form as the code shows above.

Comment: @pm100 - Clicks to Registration form on main menu form - Membershipform loads - nothing further happens - I can click the button I want manually

Comment: so put in some breakpoints, what exactly does happen

Comment: Why you need the button to click? If you want it to perform the functionality of the button when clicked, then call directly the event function your button binded too.

Comment: Całl the event function that your button is binded to on the event isClicked

Comment: @AmjadSaab , This is a work around to a complicated solution that the button contains, the button assists  , without the button complicates the internal workings  the button is the best way but i do not want the user to have to click it on load.

Comment: @JohnG it essentially has a complicated way of doing something that is LESS complicated than the alternatives i've found and then to add it to a button makes it less complicated :), this saves a-lot of time coding , I'm purposefully leaving out what it contains as i'd rather solve this problem incase i want to do it again rather then solve the inner workings without a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `PerformClick()` in the Form's constructor. At which point, the `Visible` property of the Button is false, causing `PerformClick()` to fail because in order for it to work, both the `Visible` and `Enabled` properties of the button must be true. You can confirm this by checking the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,347).

**Your options:**

1. Move the call to `PerformClick()` to the `Load` event of the form.

   ```
   private void Membershipform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Button_1.PerformClick();
   }
   ```
2. Move the code in the button's Click event handler to a separate method and call that method from the constructor.

   ```
   public Membershipform()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DoSomething();
   }

   private void DoSomething()
   {
       // Code that was originally in Button_1_Click
   }

   private void Button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DoSomething();
   }
   ```
3. Call `Button_1_Click` directly from the form constructor:

   ```
   public Membershipform()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Button_1_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for that , I went with Option one and has worked as intented. Thanks for your ttime.

Comment: It's almost always a better idea to rely on the second options. But if for some reason you want to raise the `Click` event for the button, and run all the click event handlers (theorically there might be more than one), then you can call the default action of the accessibility object or you can use reflection to raise the event. Here's how you can do it: [PerfromClick() doesn't work when the button is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70484342/3110834)